# How to create unique slugs from unique integers?

Tags: c#, function, url, slug

I have a table of entities and each has an ID identity column which is a simple incrementing integer, guaranteed to be unique per entity.  How can I create relatively short (preferably 10 characters or less) slugs from these identity integers, such that each integer should map to a unique random-looking series of characters in the set `[a-z][0-9]`?  In other words, technically it would be trivial to create slugs that are the string representation of the entities: `/foobar/1`, `/foobar/2`, etc. but how can slugs be created based on these identity integers that look more like `/foobar/34a4804bc9`, `/foobar/291e407998`, etc.?

Comment: Do you just want to generate a random jumble of numbers and letters?

Comment: This looks like a good case to use https://hashids.org/.

Comment: I have made this C# library that allows you to give things like usernames and other things as inputs and their number to get an ID: https://www.nuget.org/packages/uniqueit/1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

```
        int id = 0;
        Random r = new Random(id);
        char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890".ToCharArray();
        string output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            output += chars[r.Next(chars.Length)];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Is probably the easiest way of doing it. Replace ID with their unique number, it acts as the seed.

Comment: That doesn't guarantee uniqueness.  I'd like a function that guarantees that if the two IDs are different, the two slugs will be different.  Otherwise an extra DB check is required.

Comment: It uses the ID as a seed so it most likely will be different.